# module 'chainlit' has no attribute 'langchain_factory'

Tags: attributes, langchain, large-language-model

I downloaded the repo: https://github.com/menloparklab/falcon-langchain

I created a `virtualenv` for this one to install the `requirments.txt` and run the application.

After I run the application using the following command.

```
chainlit run app.py -w
```

But I am getting the error:

```
module 'chainlit' has no attribute 'langchain_factory'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the earlier versions of Chainlit, the `factory` concept was included as part of the API. However, after receiving feedback and evaluating its usefulness, the developers decided to remove it in order to simplify the API and avoid confusion among users.

In the latest version of Chainlit, you will no longer find the following APIs: `langchain_factory`, `langchain_run`, `langchain_postprocess`, `llama_index_factory`, and `langflow_factory`.

If your code looks like below,

```
@cl.langchain_factory
def factory():
    prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["question"])
    llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=llm, verbose=True)

    return llm_chain
```

Use the following code to use chainlit if you have installed a latest version of chainlit in your machine,

```
@cl.on_chat_start
def main():
    # Instantiate the chain for that user session
    prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["question"])
    llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=llm, verbose=True)

    # Store the chain in the user session
    cl.user_session.set("llm_chain", llm_chain)


@cl.on_message
async def main(message: str):
    # Retrieve the chain from the user session
    llm_chain = cl.user_session.get("llm_chain")  # type: LLMChain

    # Call the chain asynchronously
    res = await llm_chain.acall(message, callbacks=[cl.AsyncLangchainCallbackHandler()])

    # Do any post processing here

    # Send the response
    await cl.Message(content=res["text"]).send()
```

For more: [Migration Guide to Chainlit v0.6.0](https://docs.chainlit.io/guides/migration/0.6.0)